# Xcode: What should I use for GCC_MODEL_TUNING on Intel Mac running post-leopard OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

As title, to get max performance gain, 
should it be G5 or G4 or something else??

Thanks!

Comment: G4/G5 on an Intel Mac?  Doubtful...

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer myself.
This option is said to be ignored with machines using Intel CPUs.
However, whatever you specified, what shows up in Xcode4 is usually G5, although it will be ignored by the compiler.

Quoting this page:
http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2006/Jan/msg00334.html

> The PowerPC options available in that setting don't affect Intel
>   builds. The compiler default for Intel is correct for the processors
>   we're shipping today.